# How to use mysql-based node js (ft.json parsing)

Tags: javascript, android, mysql, json, node.js

1. I want to use myslq based on node js to communicate with the current Android server. There is a problem in trying to parse json to send data to the server.

   ```
   app.get('/main', function(req, res) {
      if (req.cookies.auth) {
         fs.readFile('main.html', function(err, data) {
         connection.query('SELECT * from datework', function(err, rows) {
         if (err) throw err;

         console.log('rows: ', rows);
         console.log('json parsing...')
         res.json(rows);

         var st = rows[0].start_time;
         var et = rows[0].end_time;
         res.json(st+" , "+ et);
         console.log(st+" , "+ et);
         });
      });
   }});
   ```

The entire row of the query statement appears, but I want to specify only start_time and end_time.

2. Finally, I want only start_time_ and end_time.

> C:\Users\KTH_LAP\Desktop\G.D\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:79
>           throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
>           ^
>
> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
>       at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:356:11)
>       at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\KTH_LAP\Desktop\G.D\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:725:10)
>       at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\KTH_LAP\Desktop\G.D\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:253:10)
>       at Query._callback (C:\Users\KTH_LAP\Desktop\G.D\app.js:56:13)
>       at Query.Sequence.end (C:\Users\KTH_LAP\Desktop\G.D\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:86:24)
>       at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (C:\Users\KTH_LAP\Desktop\G.D\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:137:8)
>       at Query.EofPacket (C:\Users\KTH_LAP\Desktop\G.D\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:121:8)
>       at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\KTH_LAP\Desktop\G.D\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:280:23)
>       at Parser.write (C:\Users\KTH_LAP\Desktop\G.D\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:75:12)
>       at Protocol.write (C:\Users\KTH_LAP\Desktop\G.D\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:39:16)

Comment: Error happens because you send the response twice with `res.json()`.

Comment: Ah Ha! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a problem related to MySQL at all.

When you make a request to your express backend application, you must send a single response accordingly, with for exemple `res.json()` or `res.send()`.
You can't send multiple response.

In your function you send it twice, this is why you get the error

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

You can just comment the line `// res.json(rows);` in your code to correct this error.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7086621/5156280) answer that explain it much better than I do.